# Which one is better for ajax post request. [unlockedActions=action, validatePost= false]

Tags: rest, security, cakephp-3.0

Which one is better for REST API?  Are there any other safe solution for ajax post request?

```
$this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', 'add');
$this->Security->setConfig('validatePost', false);
```

Comment: They will essentially both do the same thing, the only difference is that the former is more finegrained, ie it will only apply to the specified actions, while the latter will apply to all actions. I think you'd be better off if you'd explain what _exactly_ your concerns are.

Comment: I am building rest API. But i can't send post request without that config. CakePHP for backend. React for frontend. I prefer nothing to disable but no way to do that.